# Amazon s3 putObject Tagging is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am trying to add Tags while uploading to Amazon s3 with putObject method.As per documentation I have created Tagging as String type.My file got uploaded to Amazon s3 but I am unable to see object level Tags of file object with the supplied tags data.

Following code sample as per documentation

```
var params = {
  Body: <Binary String>, 
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  Key: "HappyFace.jpg", 
  Tagging: "key1=value1&key2=value2"
 };
 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response

 });
```

Comment: This code works for me in us-east-1. After the upload, my S3 object has two tags key1=value1 and key2=value2. I used the S3 console to verify the tags.

Comment: I am not using us-east-1.Actually I am using eu region.Is that tagging feature region based?I don't think so.And after hitting the api if I check the tagging for that specific object its was showing me 0 tags.Not sure why it is like that?

Comment: It works in the Dublin region (eu-west-1) just the same. How are you checking for object tags after putting the object to S3?

Answer (score 5):

This may be due to the permissions on the user. I had a similar issue but with .NET, I could add the tags but then I could not view them.

I later found that to add tags the user must have the `s3:PutObjectTagging` permission, but to view the added tags the user must also have the `s3:GetObjectTagging` permission.

Basically you want to confirm that you have both of these permissions for the user. Hope this helps